# Honeycomb Drop-down options menu. How to show?

Tags: android, android-3.0-honeycomb

How to create Drop-down options menu for Action Menu items for HoneyComb?
I have 5  Action Menu items and I want add dropdown to menu_feed_share(share button):

menu.xml

```
<menu
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

  <item android:id="@+id/menu_feed_share" android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon_share" />

  <item android:id="@+id/menu_feed_browser" android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon_web" />

  <item android:id="@+id/menu_feed_bookmark" android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon_bookmark" />

  <item android:id="@+id/menu_feed_search" android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon_search" android:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView" />

  <item android:id="@+id/menu_feed_settings" android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon_preferences" />
</menu>
```

I created SpinnerAdapter and listener, but I do not know how to show dropdown, how to assign dropdown to button share..

```
SpinnerAdapter mSpinnerAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.share_list, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
actionBar.setListNavigationCallbacks(mSpinnerAdapter, mOnNavigationListener);
```

Can anybody help me?
Thanks!

upd..
I want like something(here is menu. I need the same for Share-betton):
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, it's simple:

Thanks all!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

  <item android:id="@+id/menu_feed_share" android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon_share">
            <menu>
                <group 
                    android:id="@+id/menu_nav_group">
                        <item 
                            android:id="@+id/fb_menu"
                            android:title="Facebook"/>
                        <item 
                            android:id="@+id/twitter_menu"
                            android:title="Twitter"/>
                        <item 
                            android:id="@+id/mail_menu"
                            android:title="Mail"/>
                </group>
            </menu>
  </item>   

  <item android:id="@+id/menu_feed_browser" android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon_web" />

  <item android:id="@+id/menu_feed_bookmark" android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon_bookmark" />

  <item android:id="@+id/menu_feed_search" android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon_search" android:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView" />

  <item android:id="@+id/menu_feed_settings" android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon_preferences" />
</menu>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not an "Actions Menu" but an "Options Menu" see: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html for more information on menus in Android.

use: **onCreateOptionsMenu** and **onOptionsItemSelected** to make this work.  I belive that the dropdown menus like your picture shows are only seen in Honeycomb tablets.  Other phone android OS will have these menu options show on the bottom of the screen as seen in the link above.  Hope this answers your question.

Comment: Thank. I need dropdown menu for Motorolla XOOM. But I don't know how to implement. Tomorrow will try your variant. Thank!

Answer (score 0):

> How to create Drop-down Navigation for Action Menu items for HoneyComb?

You don't, any more than you create "Drop-down Navigation for Action Menu items" in other versions of Android. Android has never supported "Drop-down Navigation for Action Menu items". There isn't even a concept in Android of "Action Menu" -- I am guessing that you mean "options menu".

There *is* "list mode" for an action bar, which displays a Spinner, but that is not associated with an options menu item.

Comment: Yes, You are right. I guess "options menu". See picture above. I want to get the same menu as showing when You put Share button in HoneyComb gallery. Thank You! P.S. About "Action Menu item" I read here: The New Navigation: Introducing the Action Bar -- see "The New Navigation: Introducing the Action Bar" section

Comment: Menu that shows when tap on share button on these picture. Is it options menu too?

Comment: @vovs: I have no idea what you are talking about.

Comment: I need to create the same menu as on picture. In my app, when user click on Action Item(Share via) - should show same menu as on picture with my items(Facebook, twitter etc..)

Comment: @vovs: "I need to create the same menu as on picture." -- the menu that is on the picture is an options menu.